# Reading emails from an Microsoft Exchange Server Account

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am trying emails from an exchange server account.
I see a few methods to do so from .NET.
Can somebody please help me decide when to go for WebDAV or EWS or the XMLHttpRequest method?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Ews Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) . You can find lot of examples about how tos there .

Comment: This looks promising. it says it supports from Exchange Server 2007 onwards. Let me confirm the version of the Exchange server.
Thanks for the swift response.